# Connecting to Azure Databricks from ASP.NET using ODBC driver

Tags: c#, azure, odbc, azure-databricks

I am exploring an option to access the Azure Databricks SQL tables from ASP.NET MVC application.

In order to achieve that I came across an article where it states to configure ODBC Data Source.

[Configure the Databricks ODBC and JDBC drivers](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html)

Although, my setup is not successful yet (I am using

> Simba Spark 2.6 64-bit.msi

), I keep on facing error as seen in image below. I have made sure that I have right host name and port number as they are in my azure databricks portal.

[image: incorrect host name and port]

Alternatively, I tried to configure the ODBC connection setting using System.Data.Odbc DLL in my .net application. But I fear I am missing very minute configuration somewhere in either of these options to work it out. Here is the code so far I found and tried from below link.

[Trying to access SQL tables via ODBC in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334114/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-databricks-using-ado-net)

Any insight to this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the Simba ODBC DSN Driver and was able to connect to Azure Databricks with the connection string, Refer below:-

Installed Databricks ODBC Driver in my local machine.

[image]

Background Image reference:- https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download

***Went to **User DSN clicked on Add** > Selected  Simba Spark > A new window of Simba Spark ODBC Driver DSN set up appeared and I entered the following details from my Azure Databricks > Compute > Select your Compute > Scroll Down > Advanced > JDBC/ODBC Drivers> Validate the connection string with Hostname, Port and enter the same in the Simba Spark ODBC Driver DSN set up tool:-***

Azure Databricks:-

[image]

Simba Spark ODBC Driver DSN set up :-

[image]

**Make sure you add User Name as token and add Personal access token in the password.** You can generate PAT for your Azure Databricks workspace with the steps below:-

***Click on the Username at the right top > User settings > Generate new token > token name > Generate>  Copy the token and save it***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Enable SSL :-

[image]

Add HTTP path and click Ok :-

[image]

**Got connected to Datasource successfully like below:-**

[image]

When I tried to add the same datasource via System DSN with same parameters, I got the same error code as yours:-

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Configure the Databricks ODBC and JDBC drivers | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html)

Comment: I followed your steps, tried to configure User DSN instead of System DSN and still unable to connect. Actual message is this - "[Simba][ThriftExtension] (8) Authentication/authorization error occurred. Error details: Bad status with no error message: Unauthorized/Forbidden: Status code : 403". By the way, the my PAT is issued by my system admin and shared with me. Is it the issue? Should I be able to generate the token under my user account and use?

Comment: Yes, Generate PAT token for your user account, Also check if the connection string hostname is a valid one

Comment: Thank you! I was initially confused about the http path value. I ended up dropping in the HTTP path for the SQL Warehouse I wanted to connect to and it worked fine.