# ow to properly connect to Azure Databricks Warehouse from C# .NET using JDBC/ODBC driver

Tags: jdbc, odbc, databricks, azure-databricks

We are attempting to set up a connection between a C# .NET console app and Azure Databricks warehouse.
We have followed these instructions to set up and configure the ODBC driver:

```
https://docs.databricks.com/en/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#odbc-windows
```

Here is the console app code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace DatabricksJdbcExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a connection string to the Databricks warehouse.
           // string connectionString = "odbc:databricks://adb-6817616643364.19.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/827c2f60de39fa0e;";
            string connectionString = "DSN=databricksfiledsn";
            // Create a new OdbcConnection object.
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
                
            {
                // Open the connection.
                connection.Open();

                // Create a new OdbcCommand object.
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM hive_metastore.demos_dlt_loans_eugene_goldberg117.historical_txs", connection);

                // Execute the command and get the results.
                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                // Print the results to the console.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(reader.GetValue(i) + "\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // Close the reader.
                reader.Close();

                // Close the connection.
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please, not that we have two variants of the connectionString: the first one has the entire connection string and the one below it is referencing the ODBC DSN which we have set up at the beginning.
Interestingly, neither one works for us, as we are getting the same error message while using either connectionString variant:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException:  Data source not found and no default driver specified
```

What is the proper way to configure this to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the DSN setup like below:

[image]

In the **Password** field, provide the Databricks access token you created. It should look something like this: `dapi..........`.

Select `HTTP` in the Thrift Transport options.

In the **HTTP Options**, add the HTTP path you have from Databricks.
In the **SSL Options**, enable SSL.

For more details refer to this Stack Overflow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586420/connecting-to-azure-databricks-from-asp-net-using-odbc-driver).

Output:

[image]

If you want to use a connection string, format it like below:

`Driver=<path-to-driver>;Host=<server-hostname>;Port=443;HTTPPath=<http-path>;ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=<personal-access-token>`

Example:

```
Driver={Simba Spark ODBC Driver};Host=adb-436423333334855.15.azuredatabricks.net;Port=443;HTTPPath=sql/protocolv1/o/234456634855/1111-3456-jdcbhj2;ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=dapi......"
```

Output:

[image]

Make sure to install the [ODBC driver](https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download).